# C# pass child object to a method to be filled with the common properties of base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, reference, polymorphism

I have a base entity class which is derived by two class, named as Student and Department.

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }       
}

 public class Department : Entity
{
    [Required]
    [Index]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

 public class Student : Entity
    {
        [Required]
        [Index]
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }        
    }
```

Now I want to instantiate the derived classes but don't want to duplicate the common initialization codes. I have used ref out etc ways, but it is getting build errors.

```
    public Student CreateStudent()
    {
        Student student = new Student
        {
            Name = nameTextBox.Text,
            Phone = phoneTextBox.Text,
            DepartmentId = departmentComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()
        };
        SetCommonValues(ref student);
        return student;
    }

    public Department CreateDepartment()
    {
        Department department=new Department()
        {
            Name = nameTextBox.Text
        };
        SetCommonValues(ref department);
        return department;
    }

    public void SetCommonValues(ref Entity entity)
    {
        entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        entity.Created = DateTime.Now;
        entity.Modified = DateTime.Now;
        entity.CreatedBy = Constants.UserName;
        entity.ModifiedBy = Constants.UserName;            
    }
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: A constructor in the abstract class to do the work of SetCommonValues?

Comment: can you provide more details on how you are invoking your code and specifics about the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using **Extension Method** architecture

Modified caller method

```
 public Student CreateModel()
    {
        Student model = new Student
        {
            Name = nameTextBox.Text,
            Phone = phoneTextBox.Text,
            DepartmentId = departmentComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString(),                
        };
        model.SetCommonValues();
        return model;
    }
```

And the SetCommonValues method is

```
  public static Entity SetCommonValues(this Entity entity)
    {
        entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        entity.Created = DateTime.Now;
        entity.Modified = DateTime.Now;
        entity.CreatedBy = Constants.UserName;
        entity.ModifiedBy = Constants.UserName;
        return entity;
    }
```

I could mark the Extension Method as void, but for extensibility, I returned the object.

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably missing something here. Is there any particular reason you are not opting for a constructor in the abstract class like the following?

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public Entity()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        this.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
        this.Modified = this.Created;
    }

    public Entity(string createdBy, string modifiedBy) : this()
    {
        this.CreatedBy = createdBy;
        this.ModifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }
}

public class Department : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to pass the created by and modified by as parameters here. just think of 1. web api scenario (where model binds automatically by framework)

Comment: 3. I should not enforce the childs to pass parameters

Comment: Updated the answer. When you are using your entity as a model you're kind of bound to problems like these. Models are supposed to have a empty constructor because in web api that would be invoked first so the values would be populated later. And thus people use the validation attributes to validate the model.

Now, for the createdBy and modifiedBy parameters, I'm quiet sure these are not being populated by the request or even passed in the request model because these should be populated without client involvement.

Comment: I used extension method. it is much more decoupled and better IMO. :) Thanks for your contribution. 
Please don't forget to check my repo: 
https://github.com/foyzulkarim/GenericComponents

Comment: Extension methods are static methods with syntactic sugar dropped on it. For this it's quiet okay but don't forget that you can't properly unit test a static method unless it only does menial things because you won't be able to mock it easily. And your goal was to write one less line which is still there in form of an extension method now.